# Custom template types in ex_admin (Phoenix)

Tags: elixir, admin, backend, phoenix-framework

I have a blog built in Phoenix using ex_admin on the back-end and I'd like to override some of the default inputs for my blog post template.

My post has the following properties:

```
  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :image, :string   # will store as URL, will reference external host like S3
    field :created_on, :datetime
    field :content, :text

    timestamps()
  end
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Keep the `:title` field a text input
2. Create an uploader input for `:image`
3. Keep the multiple drop-down selection scheme that is default with Phoenix for `created_on`
4. Create a [Quill wysiwyg](https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/) for my `:content` (Basically put in a script that targets the `:content` text field)

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
defmodule MyBlog.ExAdmin.Post do
    use ExAdmin.Register

    register_resource MyBlog.Post do

    end

    form post do
        inputs do
            input post, :title, type: :string
            input post, :image, type: :file
            input post, :created_on, type: :datetime
            input post, :content, type: :text
        end
    end

    # Add a javascript hook that fires here to target the :content input

end
```

`:title`, `:image` and `:created_on` fields all show text inputs...the only type that I have noticed that alters the text field is `type: :password`.  Is there a way to drop in these types dynamically from the `inputs do` list, or would I have to create a custom template and reference it?

Comment: Give a couple minutes to look up the syntax for what your trying to do.

Comment: Did you try removing all the `:type` options from the `input` macros? They should automatically render correctly based on the schema meta data.

Comment: Thanks @StevePallen, found the documentation in `lib/ex_admin/form.ex`.  Removing the `:type` gives me the default behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to specify the types of the fields usually. Once exception is for `text` fields because both text and string fields are typed as string in the schema meta data.

This should work for your javascript on the form:

```
form post do
   inputs do
        input post, :title, type: :string
        input post, :image, type: :file
        input post, :created_on, type: :datetime
        input post, :content, type: :text
    end
    javascript do
      form_javascript()
    end
end
def form_javascript, do: """
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // ... 
  });
"""
```

You really don't need to use the `form_javascript` function. You can just embed can just do

```
    javascript do
      """
      $(document).ready(function() {
         // ... 
      });
      """
    end
```

However, I like to separate out the javascript, especially if its fairly long.

Comment: That worked great.  Still trying to figure out the file input.  `form.ex:346` says `* :prompt - Sets a HTML placeholder`.  Is there an example of that in action?  Tried passing a string, `input post, :image, prompt: "<input type=\"file\" name=\"pic\" accept=\"image/*\">"`....and a list `input post, :image, prompt: [input file]`

Comment: Take a look at [ex_admin_demo](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin_demo). I use file uploads with [arc_ecto](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin_demo).

Comment: `type: :file`, very easy.  Excellent work.  I'll be exploring the demo.